# Logs are missing from commands run via `heroku run`

Tags: python, heroku, logging

When I use `heroku run` to run a command, stdout and stderr only seem to go to the terminal where I ran the command. They can't be viewed with `heroku logs` or via logdrain.

Is there a way to get output from `heroku run` to be treated the same way as logs coming from, say, the scheduler?

### Repro steps

In one terminal, run:

```
$ heroku logs --tail --app my-app
```

In another terminal:

```
$ heroku run python -c "print\(\'hi\'\)" --app my-app Running python -c print\(\'hi\'\)
```

### What I expect:

The word "hi" should be visible in papertrail via logdrain, as well as via heroku logs -t

### What actually happens:

The output goes to the terminal and it doesn't end up in logdrain or the other terminal.
All I get in the logs is metadata about the process having started and exited. The actual stdout and stderr contents are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour [is documented](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#formation-dynos-vs-one-off-dynos):

> One-off dynos run attached to your terminal, with a character-by-character TCP connection for `STDIN` and `STDOUT`. This allows you to use interactive processes like a console. Since `STDOUT` is going to your terminal, the only thing recorded in the app’s logs is the startup and shutdown of the dyno.

You can use [`heroku run:detached`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run-detached) if you want to output from a one-off dyno to be captured in your logs, e.g.

```
heroku run:detached python -c "print\(\'hi\'\)" --app my-app
```

Of course, this isn't a great fit for anything interactive, but then I'm not sure it makes sense to log interactive sessions.